# Vaadin: New to JPA containters

Tags: vaadin

I am new to vaadin and JPA containers.

I've read both tutorials here:
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.usage.html

and here:
https://vaadin.com/download/jpacontainer-tutorial/#__RefHeading__3056_1659804707

And neither makes sense to me.

Can anyone out there break this stuff down for me in layman's terms:

This is how you make a container.
Then you put this grid in the container.
Then the container is sent to the database like this.

If we can start with one simple CRUD grid that saves someone's name, for example, I think I would be able to build off of that.

But these tutorials bring in so many new classes, terms, and methods at once, I can't make any sense of it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JPA with Vaadin, there are much better ways to do that than to use JPAContainer. Build a facade (e.g. an EJB) like you would do with other Java apps and bind the entities and basic lists of entities with Vaadin components.

See my [rant](https://medium.com/matti-says-about-web-apps/3-pro-tips-for-vaadin-developers-32a70997785e) about this for more details.

Comment: Link is offline, [here](https://medium.com/matti-says-about-web-apps/3-pro-tips-for-vaadin-developers-32a70997785e) is a copy.

Comment: Thanks @AlimÖzdemir! Updated the answer.